# Overwrite Selected text in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, combobox

I have a custom Editable combobox in my application, When i enter some text into it,it will start from zero th index, so that it will give old value + new vale like this.
Eg
if text is **selectedText**
result is **enteredTextSelectedText.**

How to solve this problem please help me to solve..

[image: Image of combobox]

I have tried with setting index but it is giving another problem.. I have placed a image for this reference..Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you want to show us your code so we have a place to start?

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="Combo" Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding DataItem}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Enumeration}" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedValue="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" DropDownOpened="Combo_DropDownOpened"  KeyUp="Combo_KeyUp"
                    SelectedValuePath="Value" Style="{DynamicResource cmbStyle}" DataContextChanged="Combo_DataContextChanged" Margin="4,2" Width="200" Height="23px" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="Combo_SelectionChanged" PreviewMouseMove="Combo_PreviewMouseMove"  >

Comment: This is the markup, we need the code behind, in particular the piece where the value is being concatenated.

Comment: In KeyUp event they are calling this method.if (Combo.IsEditable && !Combo.IsReadOnly)
            {
                UpdateComboItemSource();
            }

Comment: In this method they are trimming the combo text.  if (DataItem.DeviceValue.ToString().Trim() == Combo.Text.Trim())

Comment: I have a feeling that when you realize where in the code this is happening, the answer will become obvious.

Comment: @NaveenkumarR: Without seeing entire code behind we cannot help you. Also make the question more clear.

Comment: Don't post code in the comments; add it to the question instead.

Comment: @NaveenkumarR Not able to understand what you want finally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Output]

1. Right click `ComboBox` > Edit Template > Edit Copy.
2. Put this under `Window.Resources`.

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboSelectionBoxTemplate">
        <TextBlock>
           <Run Text="selectedtext"/>
           <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
3. Ctrl+F for `<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"` and replace `ContentTemplate` with `ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ComboSelectionBoxTemplate}""`.

You can change the `Binding` in `Run` accordingly. Also you can write a `Converter` accordingly if you wish so.